# Как получить @Resource в JavaEE?

Tags: java-ee, resources

Есть 2 приложения на сервере приложений GlassFish и 1 библиотека.

**Библиотека**: Оба приложения имеют доступ к интерфейсу ConnectionFactory.

```
public interface SampleConnectionFactory extends Serializable, Referenceable {
    public SampleConnection getConnection() throws ResourceException;
}
```

**1-е** приложение содержит реализацию ConnectionFactoryImpl.
**2-е** приложение должно получить доступ к этой ConnectionFactoryImpl через интерфейс ConnectionFactory посредством аннотации @Resource.

Должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
@Resource
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

В моём случае, я получаю исключения со ссылкой на неверное jndi имя.
Как я могу корректно получить фабрику из 1-го приложения?